# I am a 28 year old, i am trying to gain weight, is the following workout good enough?

Tags: workout-routines, muscle, weight-gain

I am 28, male, weight: 53kg, height: 178cm. 
After some research on the internet, i made this workout routine to do at home:

- Day 1: chest, shoulder, tris (pushups-benchpress-tricep curl-barbell
  shoulder press)
- Day 2: back and biceps and cardio(bicep curl-pullups-chinups-barbell
  curl)
- Day 3: legs and abs and cardio(squats)
- Day 4: rest
- repeat

Is this good enough, also are the workouts for each group in correct order, for eg bicep curl-pullups-chinups-bicep curl, can i do these workouts **in that order**, or it is not important? thanks.

Comment: How do you evaluate it so far? Do you have fun doing it? Btw since you are underweight, your eating habits are way off and need to be reevaluated. Only by eating more and better you will gain weight, could you comment on that? Btw, do you really have time to train that often? And why did you decide against one of the countless beginner workouts you must have encountered? I myself started with something self made but that's because I hate rigidity. Generally something like e.g. starting strength is better than anything someone with no experience can come up

Comment: When you say "to do at home", does that mean you don't have access to freeweights? Is this purely a bodyweight routine? If not, what equipment do you have access to?

Comment: If you're a beginner, why would you try to create your own program, when there are hundreds of programs available for you, made by people with decades of experience and education?

Comment: @Raditz_35  i h'v some experience in lifting, i have been doing 20kg barbell curls, 5 sets of 20 reps. but that is not producing results, i can join a gym but i am not sure where i will be after a few months as i am changing jobs. i know there are a lot of workouts available, but just wanted to keep is simple and efficient, so i took the most common exercises everyone is suggesting. the routine above itself came from a guy in quora, he has a degree related to this field( i forgot exactly) , and then i modified it a bit. the thing is i thought complex workouts like pullups and pushup are enough

Comment: @DarkHippo i have 5kg dumbells and a 20 kg barbell. i can also do pullups and chinups at home. also i have a small bench to do bench press

Comment: @Raditz_35 i eat 3 meals a day, in the morning i take whey protein with milk(started a month ago)  and bananas. sometimes i take oatmeal also, and eggs. and then i do exercises like pushups and chinups. but now i want to start a proper workout. i have also ordered digestive enzymes because i read that for some people the food doesn't get absorbed properly, because i have tried eating everything, eggs , chicken etc, but the weight remains the same.

Comment: Eat more. You need to gain weight. A lot of it.

Comment: @vikrant I would caution against editing a question in a way that changes its meaning; "gaining weight" and "gaining muscle" are very different things. There are a lot of things that can affect the ability to gain weight; building muscle is a relatively slow way. At the very least a caloric intake/breakdown would be good to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For designing a workout routine, Jeff Cavaliere recently made an excellent video on his YouTube channel (Athlean-X). I won't link it here in case it's against the rules but you can find it easily enough.

Personally, I wouldn't be doing shoulders on a chest day because there is too much overlap and you will struggle to work them both effectively. If you can really train 5-6 times a week, a typical routine is this:

- Monday: chest
- Tuesday: back
- Wednesday: legs (push)
- Thursday: shoulders
- Friday: arms
- Saturday: legs (pull)
- Sunday: rest

Work cardio into the end of 2 or 3 of the workouts if you want/need it (avoid leg days), and abs can likewise be added onto 2 or 3 workouts instead of dedicating an entire session.

Always start with the biggest compound exercises first, then move on to isolation movements towards the end of the workout. For example, on chest day, start with bench press (bar or dumbbell), maybe a mix of flat/incline/decline. Then something like cable chest flyes (single or double arm), dumbbell pullovers etc.

If you want to increase your bodyweight, try to switch from having 3 main meals a day to having 6 smaller meals (to get a more consistent calorie intake). Try to increase your carb and protein intake and keep fats to a moderate level. e.g. more rice/potato, meat or other protein-rich foods, and stick to healthier unsaturated fats (nuts etc.)

I struggle to gain weight as well, so you may find you have to force yourself to eat even when you aren't hungry, so treat it as a routine like your weight sessions, rather than just eating when you feel like it. As long as what you're eating is healthy and you keep up the training, your weight should start to rise. Obviously if you do lots of cardio then this will offset some of the weight increase, so just find a balance you are happy with.

Comment: Linking is fine, the rules require that you actually explain what you’re linking (which you’ve done sans the link itself). Suggesting a specific brand is also fine as long as it doesn’t become spam. https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/promotion

Comment: I’m not sure the workout routine is relevant to the question being asked. Vikrant seems to be interested in a Push/Pull/Legs split which is just as valid as a full body split. I appreciate Jeff Cavaliere and I’m even following one of his programs, but I’m not sure this suggestion of yours makes sense here.

Comment: "_As long as what you're eating is healthy and you keep up the training, your weight should start to rise_." This is too vague. The key component to gaining muscle/weight is to be in a calorie surplus (eating more calories than your body burns).

Comment: Jeff Cavalier is a snake oil salesman.